# Summary statistics within a tbl_summary

Tags: r, gtsummary

Can you add the mean for one continuous variable into the categorical variable in tbl_summary? For example, mean age by treatment group (in the table) by city.

I can get a count by my categorical variable but I want to get the mean of one continuous variable in my tbl_summary.

Comment: Tutorial here: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html